# ReadSoft Invoices could not create instance of class name

Tags: c#, invoice, kofax

I am currently trying to develop a custom ReadSoft Invoices plugin, nothing special.

I have gotten the plugin to work on two different machines, but the third machine I have, simply refuses to load the plugin.

The "funny" part about this, is that the third machine is a complete replica of the other two (they are all virtual machines).

The error shown when launching manager is: Plug-ins could not be loaded. (TESTPLUGIN(ClassName=TestPlugin.Test.Connect)).

I have run Regasm.exe on the dll so all the types are registered.
I have updated eilocal.ini with this:

;***********************

;* Manager *

;***********************

[Plugins::eimngr]

Plugin1=Common

Plugin2=DBMaintenance

Plugin3=ERPImport

Plugin4=InvoiceSelection

Plugin5=AutoValue

Plugin6=COLLECTOR

Plugin7=ReadSoft.InvoiceRules

Plugin8=TestPlugin

> [eimngr::TestPlugin]
>
> Name=TestPlugin
>
> Type=COM
>
> SupportIDispatch=TRUE
>
> Classname=TestPlugin.Test.Connect

I have stripped all code from the plugin, just to make sure.
This is the code I am trying to run:

```
namespace TestPlugin
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
    [ProgId("TestPlugin.Test.Connect")]
    public class TestConnect
    {
        public TestConnect()
        {

        }

        public int Connect(object objEHIApp, string sIniFile, string sIniSection)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\ProgramData\ScanSolutions\TestPlugin.txt", "Plugin Connected!");
            return 0;
        }

        public int Disconnect(object objEHIApp)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int IsVistaConverted()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the error message from manager really does not help me track down the problem, I have been looking for a log, but have not yet found one.

To debug my issue I have then attached a debugger to the manager module, which just tells me this, when trying to load my plugin:

> Could not create instance of class name TestPlugin.Test.Connect with
> clsid {B21CE504-ADDA-3174-BEB8-D359F85D9A63}.

Does anyone what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though you've mentioned that everything has been registered, it seems like the registration isn't working properly.  If you search B21CE504-ADDA-3174-BEB8-D359F85D9A63 in the registry, somewhere there you should find the path that is currently registered.  Perhaps it is still pointing to an old path?  Or the path is inaccessible to the user running the process on this system?

Comment: I tried looking through registry with regedit.exe and found the CLSID two times, though none of the entries had any path. I then tried un-registering the dll and then re-registering it with the /codebase flag, I could now see the path in registry, but the issue persists.